# escape character confusion with mysql and python

Tags: file-upload, download, werkzeug, python-unicode

I want to upload logo image from http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/
After saving it I tried the following. I'm a noob so please help..

the received stream when i upload through a html forms is

```
'GIF89a\xa0\x00\xa0\x00\xe3\x08\x00\x01\x03\x00,)\x00JB\x00g`\x00\x96\x8a\x00\xcd\xbc\x00\xe9\xd5\x00\xfd\xeb\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff!\xf9\x04\x01\n\x00\x08\x00,\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa0\x00\xa0\x00\x00\x04\xfe\x10\xc9I\xab\xbd8\xeb\xcd\x11\xf8](\x8edi\x9e\xe8\xf4\xadi\xeb\xbep|\xad\xb4l\xdfx.\xd1\xbc\xee\xff@\x0eo\x18,\x1a}\xc3\xe4q\xc9l%\x05\xca\xa6t\xbaI\x12\x0eP"u\xcbM\x16\x0e\xe0l\x8fKfZ\xc1hq\xad\xcc\x06\x9e\xd1\xe9h{n{\xc3\xd1\x039}\x9f\xb2\xdf\xf1z|\x82"~\x7f\x80Z\x83\x89UCW\x86\x86y\x88\x8a\x92\x14\x85\x8ep\x90c\x93\x93\x95\x96\x97\x81\x9a|\x9c\x9d\x9e\x91\xa0tI\x03\xa3\xaa\x98k\xa6s\xa2\xaaw\x04\x9f\xaeT\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb4\xb5fC\xa9\xb8\xb1\x06\xb3\xa5\xbbK\xa8\xbf\xc7\xc2\x99\xc4G\xc6\xc7\xc8\xba\xcb9\xcd\xce\xcf\xc3\xd18\xd3\xd4\xd5\xca\xd77\xd9\xda\xdb\xad\xdd2\xdf\xe0\xe1,\xe31\xe5\xe6\xe7 \xe9.\xa8\x06\xec\xec\xc9\xe2\xef%O\xf3\xfa\xf5\xe8\xf7$\xf9\xfa\xf6A\xf37c\x88\x00y\x01\xf5\x15\x18HP\x85A\x84\t\x152$\x080b\xc2\x85\xd6\x1az0h\xb1#Fn\xfe\x1a\x9f@\xecxq\xe2\xb5$\x01F\x92,\x99q\x1c\xca\x950?\xdaK\'\x12fL\x93\xa6P\xaa\xb4i\xd1\x00\xceMCR\xf2\xe4\xe9\xb3e\xce\xa0;\x87z\x0c`\x14(\x0f\xa1J\x87\x16`\n\x12\x94\xce\xa8Qe\xf6;\xfa4)\xd6\x95S\x9b\xeeI\x02\xc0k@\x03\xc1\x08\x0c\x10\xc0v\x00\x81\x02f\x15R\x9d9\xe8\xea\xca`n\xd5\xe6\x1d\xc0T\xad\x00\x02q\xcd\x85\xad:\xd6K\xcc\x00\x7f\xbf\x1c0P`\xc0\x80`l\xdf\xaa\xbd;wk(\xa4D\x19;\x06\x8c\x86\x00`\x01\x01\xd62}\xdc\xd1@ew\x97\x87(\xc6\xba\x90\xf3\x81\xa9P\x19\xabu\x1d\xf14\x80\xd4<\x02\x83\x05 \x00\x0c\x81\x83\x86\x1a\x93d\x85\x9a\r\xca\xd5_\xc1,l\xdc\xdb\x92\xf0\x8e\xc4o\x1b7\x9c<\x97/G\xf2<\x93$p\xba\x0cY\xddC\'[\x82\xe8v{\xf7-d\x91WG\x13\x00\xaa\xa3\xd5\x02\xd4\x07\xe4N\xb8H\xfa\xf5\x7fL\xf3\xee\xc4\x18\x8c\x01\xe0\xd0\x89\xfe%\ru\xf8\xdd\x81\xd1u\xc1y\xe6\x19\x80\x16E\xc7\x8bj\x05:"L#\xef\xd1\x80`B\xff\t\xa8\x0e\x81\x11\xfe\x91\x85|p\xd4CaD\x19\xd6W\xc7-\x11~\x14\x97l\xdc\xdd\xa5Fq\x03B\xd8\xa1%\xc90\xd8\xc9\x85\x16\xbd(]\x8c<\x8c8c.\x16:\xa7 \x8e9j\x88\x0f\x87?\xc2\xa1\xd5\x07\x17\x06\x83\xc6T\xe0\xb1\xa3\xa37(FX\x94\x1d\xfaQh\x00i<9\xb8!#I\x1a\xc2\x0f\x84W\x96\xe5\x1fwk\xf9\xd8\xa0\x91\x8b\x80\x19&\x90dQ\xc5\xcfc\xffq6\x8b\x9a\x11y\xd9\x07\x92o\x8eI\xc3\x17~\xb9%F\x1eZ\x8ef\x93\x9e&\x90\x85g\x92~\xae@$\x16447[Z\x87\xb2II\x95\x056\xca\xe4x\x95\t0\x80b\xf2<\x9a\x10\xa2!(\xfa&\x9c/uR\x8f\x8d\x07,\x9a\'\x9b\xa6\x9ezH\x9c\x81a\xe2\xde\x99J\x91\x9a\x01Y\xa2\xce\xa8\xe9\x07 \xde\x81\x89|\xb4\xf14\xa6\x10\x98\xae\x17\x0cY+\xfe\xb8\n\x87~\x01\xfc\xf1\xa99Qvf\x94\xa2\xd5&\x17]\x8f\xbf,\xd4\\g\xce\x8e\xb2P*\xd5\xea\xba\xc3:In\x1b\xe43\x08\x05\x13l,\x1f\xf5*\xe60\xbc\xca\xea\x9f\x8e<|{\x0c_\x9b\xb1\xf3\x11\xab\xb1\x1c\xebP/\xf6.\x86/\r\xb7\xae\'gg\xef\xce;F\xbd\xf6\x96\xc8\xac\x99)\xae\x80\x900\r{8\xf1\xba\xb2\xea\xb7q\xc6\xb9\xae\xe0\xdf\\ \x83\xa1.\xc1\x11\xdb\xe6&~h\xb5\xda\xacr\x7f\xae\xa2\x04G\x1d{<q\xb8D!\xf6\x1a\r\x8d@\x92\xb0\xb4r\xac\x1cf\x99\xcc\xea[\x9d\xc7\xbd\xb1\xd2\x9e\xc5\xa3\xf8Y\x01\xcaI\x0e6\xb1\xd1GGj\xf3\n\x01\xb8\x8a\x96\xd3\x16\x08]\xf1\xc6\x1fd\xdb\x93\x7fV+\x9d\xf1\xb6\xbb\xf2 \xafRK~W\xa0i\xc0\xc9D\xaeg s\x9d6\xc7\xeb\xb5\x9d,IH\x93\xfd2.vk\x00\xf5W\x8c\x81\xfd\x01\xce6\xc9\xd4\xdc\xbf\x80\xff4xT\xbf\xe2\x9d\xdc\x7f\xcb\xae \xa9\xc8\xfe\xaa\x04\xde\xc1\xe3<\xe9\xfd\x10\xcbT\x15n\xf9\x96\x1fP\xfd\x87\xe6\xa5\xaa\r\xb9\xe1\x00\xfc\x1c\x95\xc7\xbe4\x1a\x18\xea\x84\xa8-\xb63\x9e\x0fq\xfbYT\xa5R@oc\x86K\xfb\x08\x9c\x93\xc8:\x00%\xf3\xdd\xbb\xcb\xfb\r\x16@\xc6\xc3\xff\x93/L\'s\x8b\xdf\xa0\xc9|!O\x01 \xb7\xfd\xa5\xe5|\xb3\x8e8\xdfo\x19\x96G\xc9\xd1\x9f\xf0\xb9\xf1`\x9b\xaeT\x86\xe5\xf3|\x80\xcf\x99\xffD\xfc\xf4\xecO\xbd\xfb<6\x03f\xa1\xcf\x81\xf1\x1e\x8fJ\xb7\xbfGL\xccuC\xb9\x9a\xef03\x1e\x01\xea`}\x12\xa1\x95\xb2N\xe3\x8b2!\xf0I\xf6C\x01\x04\xe7\xd1\xa8\xe4\xf5\x84*\xa1\xd9\xd4b0rA\x98YjOV\xbb\x88\x18B\xc32\x12\x92\x0e\x00\xe4\n\xcd\xef\x02\x98Ax\xe4\xab\x80\x1d;\xc8\x0c\xe7\xc7$\xd8\xa9\xc2\x81\xcc\xb8a\xc1\x9c\x91%R\x80\xe6\x03%\xdc\xd9\t\xbfG\xc0!\xfe"\x0b\x08"N\x12\x89\x06\xa3\x07a\r\x87?\xca\x82\xfe\xbe\x94F\xc3%R\taXd\xd9c\x92\x11"\xace\xecjU\x9c\x02\x03\x9dx\x07h]\xc9-\x17k\x9dn\xa6\xd4\x865\xb21\x0cX;Mh\xe8\xa6\n:\xbe\xa2+w\xc4\xe0\xc6\x92\xf8;/\x06\xc1\x8e\x05\xa3\x1b\xd1\x8e\x88\xc4\x00\xda&\x11H\t\xa3\x8b\x9a%\x93\x940\'cR\xb3\x0cn\x1a\x99\xb2\xdcX\x10<\x99L\xe3&\xc3v*4\x9aIq\xaa0%Wb\x96$\x8f}\xe6p\x80)\xca\x14\x1f\xe9\x8a\xa0x\xd0&6\xfb\x82\xd2\xde\x02\xb06\xd2\xb2\x16I\x90$\xb5x\xd8\xac*\xa9r\x19\xc1|\x1bb^\x885\xfa\xb4\xee\x8c\xbfD\xa6\x8c&\xb70V\xf4l\x96\x86<\xc54_\xb7<]\xcao1\xa3\x90\x98&\xa3\xc1\'\x98\xf4m\x16\xa9\xb0f*\xfd\xf8\x0e\xc3\x08\x13;T\xe9\x8d\x8a\x889Ev\xde\xa3\x9c$\xaa\xc7\xb0\xe6\xb7\xa5\xe7\xa9"\x9a\x14Q\xcd;\x9f\x85\x98\xe0\xf10%\x81\x11\xa7(\xef\xb9M\x0ce\xc13A\x02`\x1f\xfe\xb3\xb9\xca\x15\xdc\x12\x17\x98`^\xe9\x90xF{jd`\xdf\xd4G\xcb|\xc8\x8f$B\xcaD!\xf1\x9a6\x8a\xf8\x91+$\xc3\x9f\xfc\xf1\xe8G\x9f\xa6\xd2c\xd8,>\x12\x9d\x85I\xcd5S\x9a\xf2\xe0\xa2\xcfb\xc4\xf2ZuF\x9e\xf6\xd4\xa7!\xa5\x860T\x96<\xa3\x1e\x15\xa9\x7f\xc3\x85i|!\xa7\xd3\xb8OX\x14\xf5G\xb2<\xf6\xbc\x03it\xa7Y\r\xa8\xf5\xc4U\x19\xb5\x00\xeb5\xa0\x01\x99S\x9fz\xb7\xa4\x8eGi\x9c\x04\xe7(\xd6\xca\xd6\xb6F\x95\xac\xc53 J\xeb*\xb8\xbc\xe6G\x8a\xa9\x14\x18_\xd5W\xd3\xf7\x80P\xada\xad+\xba\x1c\xc1\x17\xdd\x08v\xb0(t\xab@\xf6\n\xd9\xd4\xa9.!\x8f\xad\xac\x13\xfc\xda\x0e\xcd\x92\x83\xb3\x01K\xacgA\xea(sdv\xb4/X\xac\xaaD\x8b\xdaK]\xf6\x17\xa7m-\x0c*R?\xca\xca\x96\xb0\xf8k\x1ako\xdb\xb5\r\xfeaI\xbc\xfdAM\x1cF\x97\xe0\x9eH\x88\xcf\x02\xaeq\xdd0\xb0A\xe5.\x97\xb9\xc8u\xees\xa1k5\xe9N\x97\xbaX\xdb\xedu\x915\xb1\xedZQ\xbb\xde\xdd\\\r\xc3;[\xdb\x92\x17\x1b\xe3<\xaf\x11\x16\x1a\x8d\x08\x00\x00;'
```

I receive the above using req.file["name"] and store it in the Mysql.

now when i read back from MySQL I get,

```
u'GIF89axa0x00xa0x00xe3x08x00x01x03x00,)x00JBx00g`x00x96x8ax00xcdxbcx00xe9xd5x00xfdxebx00xffxffxffxffxffxffxffxffxffxffxffxffxffxffxffxffxffxffxffxffxffxffxffxff!xf9x04x01\nx00x08x00,x00x00x00x00xa0x00xa0x00x00x04xfex10xc9Ixabxbd8xebxcdx11xf8](x8edix9exe8xf4xadixebxbep|xadxb4lxdfx.xd1xbcxeexff@x0eox18,x1a}xc3xe4qxc9l%x05xcaxa6txbaIx12x0eP"uxcbMx16x0exe0lx8fKfZxc1hqxadxccx06x9exd1xe9h{n{xc3xd1x039}x9fxb2xdfxf1z|x82"~x7fx80Zx83x89UCWx86x86yx88x8ax92x14x85x8epx90cx93x93x95x96x97x81x9a|x9cx9dx9ex91xa0tIx03xa3xaax98kxa6sxa2xaawx04x9fxaeTxb0xb1xb2xb4xb5fCxa9xb8xb1x06xb3xa5xbbKxa8xbfxc7xc2x99xc4Gxc6xc7xc8xbaxcb9xcdxcexcfxc3xd18xd3xd4xd5xcaxd77xd9xdaxdbxadxdd2xdfxe0xe1,xe31xe5xe6xe7 xe9.xa8x06xecxecxc9xe2xef%Oxf3xfaxf5xe8xf7$xf9xfaxf6Axf37cx88x00yx01xf5x15x18HPx85Ax84\tx152$x080bxc2x85xd6x1az0hxb1#Fnxfex1ax9f@xecxqxe2xb5$x01Fx92,x99qx1cxcax950?xdaK\'x12fLx93xa6Pxaaxb4ixd1x00xceMCRxf2xe4xe9xb3excexa0;x87zx0c`x14(x0fxa1Jx87x16`\nx12x94xcexa8Qexf6;xfa4)xd6x95Sx9bxeeIx02xc0k@x03xc1x08x0cx10xc0vx00x81x02fx15Rx9d9xe8xeaxca`nxd5xe6x1dxc0Txadx00x02qxcdx85xad:xd6Kxccx00x7fxbfx1c0P`xc0x80`lxdfxaaxbd;wk(xa4Dx19;x06x8cx86x00`x01x01xd62}xdcxd1@ewx97x87(xc6xbax90xf3x81xa9Px19xabux1dxf14x80xd4<x02x83x05 x00x0cx81x83x86x1ax93dx85x9a\rxcaxd5_xc1,lxdcxdbx92xf0x8exc4ox1b7x9c<x97/Gxf2<x93$pxbax0cYxddC\'[x82xe8v{xf7-dx91WGx13x00xaaxa3xd5x02xd4x07xe4Nxb8Hxfaxf5x7fLxf3xeexc4x18x8cx01xe0xd0x89xfe%\ruxf8xddx81xd1uxc1yxe6x19x80x16Exc7x8bjx05:"L#xefxd1x80`Bxff\txa8x0ex81x11xfex91x85|pxd4CaDx19xd6Wxc7-x11~x14x97lxdcxddxa5Fqx03Bxd8xa1%xc90xd8xc9x85x16xbd(]x8c<x8c8c.x16:xa7 x8e9jx88x0fx87?xc2xa1xd5x07x17x06x83xc6Txe0xb1xa3xa37(FXx94x1dxfaQhx00i<9xb8!#Ix1axc2x0fx84Wx96xe5x1fwkxf9xd8xa0x91x8bx80x19&x90dQxc5xcfcxffq6x8bx9ax11yxd9x07x92ox8eIxc3x17~xb9%Fx1eZx8efx93x9e&x90x85gx92~xae@$x16447[Zx87xb2IIx95x056xcaxe4xx95\t0x80bxf2<x9ax10xa2!(xfa&x9c/uRx8fx8dx07,x9a\'x9bxa6x9ezHx9cx81axe2xdex99Jx91x9ax01Yxa2xcexa8xe9x07 xdex81x89|xb4xf14xa6x10x98xaex17x0cY+xfexb8\nx87~x01xfcxf1xa99Qvfx94xa2xd5&x17]x8fxbf,xd4\\gxcex8exb2P*xd5xeaxbaxc3:Inx1bxe43x08x05x13l,x1fxf5*xe60xbcxcaxeax9fx8e<|{x0c_x9bxb1xf3x11xabxb1x1cxebP/xf6.x86/\rxb7xae\'ggxefxce;Fxbdxf6x96xc8xacx99)xaex80x900\r{8xf1xbaxb2xeaxb7qxc6xb9xaexe0xdf\\ x83xa1.xc1x11xdbxe6&~hxb5xdaxacrx7fxaexa2x04Gx1d{<qxb8D!xf6x1a\rx8d@x92xb0xb4rxacx1cfx99xccxea[x9dxc7xbdxb1xd2x9exc5xa3xf8Yx01xcaIx0e6xb1xd1GGjxf3\nx01xb8x8ax96xd3x16x08]xf1xc6x1fdxdbx93x7fV+x9dxf1xb6xbbxf2 xafRK~Wxa0ixc0xc9Dxaeg sx9d6xc7xebxb5x9d,IHx93xfd2.vkx00xf5Wx8cx81xfdx01xce6xc9xd4xdcxbfx80xff4xTxbfxe2x9dxdcx7fxcbxae xa9xc8xfexaax04xdexc1xe3<xe9xfdx10xcbTx15nxf9x96x1fPxfdx87xe6xa5xaa\rxb9xe1x00xfcx1cx95xc7xbe4x1ax18xeax84xa8-xb63x9ex0fqxfbYTxa5R@ocx86Kxfbx08x9cx93xc8:x00%xf3xddxbbxcbxfb\rx16@xc6xc3xffx93/L\'sx8bxdfxa0xc9|!Ox01 xb7xfdxa5xe5|xb3x8e8xdfox19x96Gxc9xd1x9fxf0xb9xf1`x9bxaeTx86xe5xf3|x80xcfx99xffDxfcxf4xecOxbdxfb<6x03fxa1xcfx81xf1x1ex8fJxb7xbfGLxccuCxb9x9axef03x1ex01xea`}x12xa1x95xb2Nxe3x8b2!xf0Ixf6Cx01x04xe7xd1xa8xe4xf5x84*xa1xd9xd4b0rAx98YjOVxbbx88x18Bxc32x12x92x0ex00xe4\nxcdxefx02x98Axxe4xabx80x1d;xc8x0cxe7xc7$xd8xa9xc2x81xccxb8axc1x9cx91%Rx80xe6x03%xdcxd9\txbfGxc0!xfe"x0bx08"Nx12x89x06xa3x07a\rx87?xcax82xfexbex94Fxc3%R\taXdxd9cx92x11"xacexecjUx9cx02x03x9dxx07h]xc9-x17kx9dnxa6xd4x865xb21x0cX;Mhxe8xa6\n:xbexa2+wxc4xe0xc6x92xf8;/x06xc1x8ex05xa3x1bxd1x8ex88xc4x00xda&x11H\txa3x8bx9a%x93x940\'cRxb3x0cnx1ax99xb2xdcXx10<x99Lxe3&xc3v*4x9aIqxaa0%Wbx96$x8f}xe6px80)xcax14x1fxe9x8axa0xxd0&6xfbx82xd2xdex02xb06xd2xb2x16Ix90$xb5xxd8xac*xa9rx19xc1|x1bb^x885xfaxb4xeex8cxbfDxa6x8c&xb70Vxf4lx96x86<xc54_xb7<]xcao1xa3x90x98&xa3xc1\'x98xf4mx16xa9xb0f*xfdxf8x0exc3x08x13;Txe9x8dx8ax889Evxdexa3x9c$xaaxc7xb0xe6xb7xa5xe7xa9"x9ax14Qxcd;x9fx85x98xe0xf10%x81x11xa7(xefxb9Mx0cexc13Ax02`x1fxfexb3xb9xcax15xdcx12x17x98`^xe9x90xF{jd`xdfxd4Gxcb|xc8x8f$BxcaD!xf1x9a6x8axf8x91+$xc3x9fxfcxf1xe8Gx9fxa6xd2cxd8,>x12x9dx85Ixcd5Sx9axf2xe0xa2xcfbxc4xf2ZuFx9exf6xd4xa7!xa5x860Tx96<xa3x1ex15xa9x7fxc3x85i|!xa7xd3xb8OXx14xf5Gxb2<xf6xbcx03itxa7Y\rxa8xf5xc4Ux19xb5x00xeb5xa0x01x99Sx9fzxb7xa4x8eGix9cx04xe7(xd6xcaxd6xb6Fx95xacxc53 Jxeb*xb8xbcxe6Gx8axa9x14x18_xd5Wxd3xf7x80Pxadaxad+xbax1cxc1x17xddx08vxb0(txab@xf6\nxd9xd4xa9.!x8fxadxacx13xfcxdax0excdx92x83xb3x01KxacgAxea(sdvxb4/XxacxaaDx8bxdaK]xf6x17xa7m-x0c*R?xcaxcax96xb0xf8kx1akoxdbxb5\rxfeaIxbcxfdAMx1cFx97xe0x9eHx88xcfx02xaeqxdd0xb0Axe5.x97xb9xc8uxeesxa1k5xe9Nx97xbaXxdbxedux915xb1xedZQxbbxdexdd\\\rxc3;[xdbx92x17x1bxe3<xafx11x16x1ax8dx08x00x00;'
```

All the escape characters are gone now, i want to display this file and i'm not able to on the HTML after i send a response.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this ? I'm not able to get through this for more than a week.

I'm using python2.7.3 and werkzeug and mysql-connector for python.

The example code in one of the github uses this

```
'R0lGODlhoACgAOMIAAEDACwpAEpCAGdgAJaKAM28AOnVAP3rAP/////////\n//////////////////////yH5BAEKAAgALAAAAACgAKAAAAT+EMlJq704680R+F0ojmRpnuj0rWnrv\nnB8rbRs33gu0bzu/0AObxgsGn3D5HHJbCUFyqZ0ukkSDlAidctNFg7gbI9LZlrBaHGtzAae0eloe25\n7w9EDOX2fst/xenyCIn5/gFqDiVVDV4aGeYiKkhSFjnCQY5OTlZaXgZp8nJ2ekaB0SQOjqphrpnOiq\nncEn65UsLGytLVmQ6m4sQazpbtLqL/HwpnER8bHyLrLOc3Oz8PRONPU1crXN9na263dMt/g4SzjMeX\nm5yDpLqgG7OzJ4u8lT/P69ej3JPn69kHzN2OIAHkB9RUYSFCFQYQJFTIkCDBiwoXWGnowaLEjRm7+G\np9A7Hhx4rUkAUaSLJlxHMqVMD/aSycSZkyTplCqtGnRAM5NQ1Ly5OmzZc6gO4d6DGAUKA+hSocWYAo\nSlM6oUWX2O/o0KdaVU5vuSQLAa0ADwQgMEMB2AIECZhVSnTno6spgbtXmHcBUrQACcc2FrTrWS8wAf\n78cMFBgwIBgbN+qvTt3ayikRBk7BoyGAGABAdYyfdzRQGV3l4coxrqQ84GpUBmrdR3xNIDUPAKDBSA\nADIGDhhqTZIWaDcrVX8EsbNzbkvCOxG8bN5w8ly9H8jyTJHC6DFndQydbguh2e/ctZJFXRxMAqqPVA\ntQH5E64SPr1f0zz7sQYjAHg0In+JQ11+N2B0XXBeeYZgBZFx4tqBToiTCPv0YBgQv8JqA6BEf6RhXx\nw1ENhRBnWV8ctEX4Ul2zc3aVGcQNC2KElyTDYyYUWvShdjDyMOGMuFjqnII45aogPhz/CodUHFwaDx\nlTgsaOjNyhGWJQd+lFoAGk8ObghI0kawg+EV5blH3dr+digkYuAGSaQZFHFz2P/cTaLmhF52QeSb45\nJwxd+uSVGHlqOZpOeJpCFZ5J+rkAkFjQ0N1tah7JJSZUFNsrkeJUJMIBi8jyaEKIhKPomnC91Uo+NB\nyyaJ5umnnpInIFh4t6ZSpGaAVmizqjpByDegYl8tPE0phCYrhcMWSv+uAqHfgH88ak5UXZmlKLVJhd\ndj78s1Fxnzo6yUCrV6rrDOkluG+QzCAUTbCwf9SrmMLzK6p+OPHx7DF+bsfMRq7Ec61Av9i6GLw23r\nidnZ+/OO0a99pbIrJkproCQMA17OPG6suq3cca5ruDfXCCDoS7BEdvmJn5otdqscn+uogRHHXs8cbh\nEIfYaDY1AkrC0cqwcZpnM6ludx72x0p7Fo/hZAcpJDjax0UdHavMKAbiKltMWCF3xxh9k25N/Viud8\nba78iCvUkt+V6BpwMlErmcgc502x+u1nSxJSJP9Mi52awD1V4yB/QHONsnU3L+A/zR4VL/indx/y64\ngqcj+qgTeweM86f0Qy1QVbvmWH1D9h+alqg254QD8HJXHvjQaGOqEqC22M54PcftZVKVSQG9jhkv7C\nJyTyDoAJfPdu8v7DRZAxsP/ky9MJ3OL36DJfCFPASC3/aXlfLOOON9vGZZHydGf8LnxYJuuVIbl83y\nAz5n/RPz07E+9+zw2A2ahz4HxHo9Kt79HTMx1Q7ma7zAzHgHqYH0SoZWyTuOLMiHwSfZDAQTn0ajk9\nYQqodnUYjByQZhZak9Wu4gYQsMyEpIOAOQKze8CmEF45KuAHTvIDOfHJNipwoHMuGHBnJElUoDmAyX\nc2Qm/R8Ah/iILCCJOEokGowdhDYc/yoL+vpRGwyVSCWFYZNljkhEirGXsalWcAgOdeAdoXcktF2udb\nqbUhjWyMQxYO01o6KYKOr6iK3fE4MaS+DsvBsGOBaMb0Y6IxADaJhFICaOLmiWTlDAnY1KzDG4ambL\ncWBA8mUzjJsN2KjSaSXGqMCVXYpYkj33mcIApyhQf6YqgeNAmNvuC0t4CsDbSshZJkCS1eNisKqlyG\ncF8G2JeiDX6tO6Mv0SmjCa3MFb0bJaGPMU0X7c8XcpvMaOQmCajwSeY9G0WqbBmKv34DsMIEztU6Y2\nKiDlFdt6jnCSqx7Dmt6XnqSKaFFHNO5+FmODxMCWBEaco77lNDGXBM0ECYB/+s7nKFdwSF5hgXumQe\nEZ7amRg39RHy3zIjyRCykQh8Zo2iviRKyTDn/zx6EefptJj2Cw+Ep2FSc01U5ry4KLPYsTyWnVGnvb\nUpyGlhjBUljyjHhWpf8OFaXwhp9O4T1gU9UeyPPa8A2l0p1kNqPXEVRm1AOs1oAGZU596t6SOR2mcB\nOco1srWtkaVrMUzIErrKri85keKqRQYX9VX0/eAUK1hrSu6HMEX3Qh2sCh0q0D2CtnUqS4hj62sE/z\naDs2Sg7MBS6xnQeooc2R2tC9YrKpEi9pLXfYXp20tDCpSP8rKlrD4axprb9u1Df5hSbz9QU0cRpfgn\nkiIzwKucd0wsEHlLpe5yHXuc6FrNelOl7pY2+11kTWx7VpRu97dXA3DO1vbkhcb4zyvERYajQgAADs\n='
```

This works perfectly and its all normal text.. how can i get this one.  ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found what was wrong, For anyone with the same problem.. File upload sends in hex format or raw strings when received. The uploaded file stream needs to be Encoded with 'base64' and stored in mysql. Mysql tries to remove the escape characters when trying to store the raw strings so the stream needs to be encoded.

```
req.file.stream.read().encode('base64')
```

when sending the file to the client decode and set the mime type of the content as response.

This solved my issue.